# Legend disappears

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first post here, but I'll try to provide all the necessary information.

I am using ggplot2 to create a map showing the Domestic PAX volumes by airport for American Airlines in the year 2019. Everything works now with the exception of the legend that, for some reason won't show up. I've checked many other similar posts and I have read that it must be some problem with *aes*. I have noticed that the legends disappear after applying the scale_size_continuous, scale_alpha_continuous and scale_color_viridis, but I have not been able to solve it.

I have one dataframe (AA_BMap) consisting of the number of seats, latitude and longitude values.

Sample:

```
structure(list(Airport.Name = c("Grand Rapids", "Grand Rapids", 
"Martha's Vineyard", "Nantucket", "Nantucket", "Gunnison", "Richmond (US)", 
"Richmond (US)", "Duluth", "Kalispell", "Worcester", "Cheyenne Regional Apt", 
"Cheyenne Regional Apt", "Marquette", "Billings", "Billings", 
"Garden City", "Del Rio International Apt", "Springfield (US) IL", 
"Waterloo"), Seats = c(11.5625, 11.5625, 13.984, 16.416, 16.416, 
17.28, 18.493, 18.493, 21.925, 22.724, 24.9, 25.75, 25.75, 26.9075, 
27.664, 27.664, 32.038, 32.226, 34.134, 35), Carrier.Name = c("American 
Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", 
"American Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", 
"American Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", 
"American Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", 
"American Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", 
"American Airlines", "American Airlines", "American Airlines", 
"American Airlines"), Longitude = c("-85.522800000000004", 
"-85.522796630000002", "-70.6143", "-70.060203549999997", 
"-70.060199999999995", "-106.93300000000001", "-77.319699999999997", 
"-77.319702149999998", "-92.193600000000004", "-114.256", 
"-71.875699999999995", "-104.81199650000001", "-104.812", 
"-87.395399999999995", "-108.54299930000001", "-108.54300000000001", 
"-100.724", "-100.92700000000001", "-89.677899999999994", 
"-92.400299070000003"), Latitude = c("42.880800000000001", 
"42.880798339999998", "41.393099999999997", "41.253101350000001", 
"41.253100000000003", "38.533900000000003", "37.505200000000002", 
"37.505199429999998", "46.842100000000002", "48.310499999999998", 
"42.267299999999999", "41.155700680000002", "41.155700000000003", "46.3536", 
"45.807701109999996", "45.807699999999997", "37.927500000000002", 
"29.374199999999998", "39.844099999999997", "42.55709839")), row.names = 
c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(viridis)
library(mapproj)
'''
USMap <- borders("state", colour = "grey", fill = "white")
mybreaks <- c(0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 1, 7)
'''
AA_BMAP <- ggplot() + theme_void() + USMap +
geom_point(data = AA_BMap, aes(x = as.numeric(Longitude), y = as.numeric(Latitude), color = 
AA_BMap$Seats, size = AA_BMap$Seats, alpha = AA_BMap$Seats), shape=20, stroke=FALSE) +
scale_size_continuous(guide = "legend", name="Seats [thousands]", trans="log", range=c(1,12), 
breaks=mybreaks) +
scale_alpha_continuous(name="Seats [thousands]", trans="log", range=c(0.1, .9), breaks=mybreaks) +
scale_color_viridis(option="magma", trans="log", breaks=mybreaks, name="Seats [thousands]" ) + 
coord_map() +
guides( color = guide_legend()) + 
theme(
 axis.line=element_blank(),
 axis.text.x=element_blank(),
 axis.text.y=element_blank(),
 axis.title.x=element_blank(),
 axis.title.y=element_blank(),
 axis.ticks=element_blank(),
 panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
 panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(),
 legend.position = c(0.1, 0.8),
 legend.title = element_text(colour="white", size = 16, face='bold'),
 text = element_text(color = "#22211d"),
 plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
 panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
 legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA),
 )
```

I am adding an image of what I have so far. It is great, it's only missing the legend.

[Domestic PAX Distribution of AA by Airport in 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mydv.png)

My idea was for the legend to look something like this:

[Model legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdbZa.png)

Thank you very much in advance, guys!

Comment: Can you supply a sample or simulation of your data (AA_BMap)?  It looks like it would only need the Latitude, Longitude and Seats columns.

Comment: @BrianFisher done!

Comment: It's more helpful if you can supply a sample as code rather than an image.  An easy way to do it if the data isn't sensitive is `dput( AA_BMap[1:20,])` and paste the result in a code block.  This will allow someone to paste it into their R session and recreate the first 20 rows of your data frame

Comment: @BrianFisher I did as you said. I hope this is more helpful now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are supplying breaks that are outside of the range of your data.

```
 range(AA_BMap$Seats)
# [1] 11.5625 35.0000
mybreaks <- c(0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 1, 7)
```

So the highest patch for your legend is 7, while the lowest point in (at least the data sample) is 11.
Either removing all of the instances of `breaks = mybreaks` from your calls to `scale_...` would work as would setting mybreaks to include items within the range of your Seats data.  For example, using your sample data:

```
mybreaks = c( 17, 25, 34)
AA_BMap %>%
      ggplot() + 
      theme_void() + 
      USMap +
      geom_point( aes(x = as.numeric(Longitude), 
                                     y = as.numeric(Latitude), 
                                     color =  Seats, 
                                     size = Seats, 
                                     alpha = Seats),
                 shape=20, 
                 stroke=FALSE
                 ) +
      scale_size_continuous(guide = "legend", 
                            name="Seats [thousands]", 
                            trans="log", 
                            range=c(1,12), 
                            breaks=mybreaks
                            ) +
      scale_alpha_continuous(name="Seats [thousands]",
                             trans="log",
                             range=c(0.1, .9),
                             breaks=mybreaks
                             ) +
      scale_color_viridis(option="magma",
                          trans="log",
                          breaks=mybreaks,
                          name="Seats [thousands]"
                          ) +
      coord_map() +
      guides( color = guide_legend()) +
      theme(
            axis.line=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(),
            # legend.position =  c(0.1, 0.8),
            legend.title = element_text(
                  # colour="white", 
                  size = 16, face='bold'),
            text = element_text(color = "#22211d"),
            plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
            legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA),
      )
```

returns
[image: sample with legend]

In addition to the changes to mybreaks, ggplot prefers unquoted `color = Seats` over `color = AA_Map$Seats`.  It provides a little safety to encourage you to use columns of the same data frame.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem.
I can't believe it was all due to such a small silly thing.